# Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby`

Tags: virtualbox, docker, syslog

Can someone explain what the following error in`/var/log/syslog` means? I don't know if I picked the relevant part, there is a lot more information in the log.

`Feb  4 10:57:51 chriad-VirtualBox dockerd[1313]: time="2019-02-04T10:57:51.039077089+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc`

`Feb  4 10:57:51 chriad-VirtualBox dockerd[1313]: time="2019-02-04T10:57:51.039751889+01:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\". Reconnecting..." module=grpc`

`Feb  4 10:57:51 chriad-VirtualBox dockerd[1313]: time="2019-02-04T10:57:51.039822044+01:00" level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: connection refused\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby`

and this goes on for a long time...

What can I do to make this error go away?

```
uname -a
Linux chriad-VirtualBox 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29     16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
```

I use virtualbox 5.2.26.

```
systemctl | grep failed
● apport-autoreport.service          loaded failed failed    Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled             
● containerd.service                 loaded failed failed    containerd container runtime                                          
● vboxadd-service.service            loaded failed failed    vboxadd-service.service
```